# Disable Unnecessary Log Collections for Azure Functions App

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions

I run a Kusto query for detect the which logs are collecting in my C# function app and then I see there is too much unnecessary log collections in storage : [image]

I want disable all log collections except for "AppExceptions", all other logs are not necessary for me. (Especially I want to turn off "AppRequests" and "AppMetrics") How can I disable them?

Azure functions version: v3

Comment: Change logging settings on your Function App in the Azure Portal, under Monitoring > Diagnostic settings

Comment: @Dai I tried your solution but seems like LogAnalytics still collecting all logs. Do you have any idea?

Comment: You also need to delete your previous logs...

Comment: @Dai I'm filtering logs from the last 2 hour and I added diagnostic setting you mentioned 2 hour ago. Log analytics still collecting all log types in the last 2 hours too

Comment: Look at your Log Analytics resources (they might be listed as "Solutions" for some reason) - browser the Portal screens/blades to see where the logs are coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to collect all log information from your app you have to configure the log categories in your app.

1. Mention the log category to ignore the log level which you don't want to add in Application insights.
   **`Function.<YOUR_FUNCTION_NAME>`**, **`Function.<YOUR_FUNCTION_NAME>.User`**, **`Host.Aggregator`**, **`Host.Results`**, **`Microsoft`** & **`Worker`**.

```json
{
  "version": "2.0",

  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request" // Exclude the Request
      }
    },
    "fileLoggingMode": "always",
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Error", // It will log Error  or higher level log
      "Host.Results": "Error",
      "Function": "Error",
      "Host.Aggregator": "Error",
      "Function.Function1": "Error",
      "Function.Function1.User" : "Error"
    }
  }
}
```

2. Use **"excludedTypes"** to avoid collecting the mentioned log level. In the above code it will ignore the Request level logs.
3. Configure the log levels [Ms-Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/configure-monitoring?tabs=v2#configure-log-levels) has Higher level so that it will collect high priority level logs like Error, Critical and None. In the above **host.json** file I am collection all High level logs Error or higher.

You can edit **host.json** in App Service Editor / Kudu if your app already in production.

[image]

4. If you want to ***disable the default built-in logging*** you can **remove** the **`AzureWebJobsDashboard`** in an Application Settings. (It is recommended for High load function).

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Do you think do I need add specific function names to "logLevel" for change the log level in the host.json? Because I need ignoring these log types for all functions, not for some specific functions

Comment: Yes. You can try to add specific function name and mention the log level according.

Comment: Doesn't look like correct answer to me as it will only work for the sampling logs. At least according to the example provided. Also there is no such log level as Request. Also doesn't provide a way to disable the logs as requested. Downvoted.