# How to exclude Request log entries in Azure Function logs?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

How can I exclude the "Request" log entries in an Azure Function application's log output?

[image: example entries]

These entries seem to be generated by the Function runtime itself and are not entries that I am creating manually or interested in seeing. They appear to be mostly related to Storage polling for Blob Triggers, etc. I used to not see these entries but now they're filling up my logs and make it hard to locate the logs that I am interested in.

I do have some logging configuration in my host.json file, but it does not appear to change anything. It looks like below ...

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    },
    "logLevel": {
      "WhatInBoxFunctions": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it fine if you don't get both Request and Response Headers in Logs ?

Comment: @Harshitha Correct. On Azure, in the Function Log Output where it shows the live logs, I'd like the exclude the Request and Response data.

Comment: Could you please share your Azure Function code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Thanks @[Delliganesh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74485195/21525734), I followed some configuration.
- As you mentioned in above screenshot that the request ID logs should be Ignored.
- For logs entries and request id's I have created function app works locally.

[image]

[image]

**Request type excluded** by this I can able to Ignore request id's in App insight logs.

Updated **host.json** module:

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "logging": {
      "applicationInsights": {
        "samplingSettings": {
          "isEnabled": true,
          "excludedTypes": "Request"
        }
      },
      "logLevel": {
        "default": "Warning",
        "MyFunctionApp": "Information"
      }
    }
  }
```

- check below for log stream:

[image]

Comment: this not works for me, everything is logged in .NET  7 :(

Comment: Whats different here from the question?