# Azure Function (.NET 7) Excessive Logging

Tags: c#, .net, logging, azure-functions, .net-7.0

When running the function app in VS or Azure, HTTP request logs are generated as per below screenshot. This makes it incredibly difficult to find/ read useful logs.

[image: Console Window]

This happens for both the SecretClient and BlobServiceClient. All Azure clients are registered as follows:

[image: Client Registration]

Would anyone be able to suggest how to suppress the HTTP request logs but still keep the default logging level of the application to 'Information' so that actual application logs are still visible?

I tried setting default application log level to 'Warning' but that hides all other application logs.

I tried filtering out HTTPClient logs as per below code snippet but didn't result into anything either:

```
.ConfigureLogging(builder =>
    {
        builder.AddFilter("System.Net.Http.HttpClient", LogLevel.Warning);
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

- The code snippet that you have given is to filter out logs from the “System.Net.Http.HttpClient” category with a minimum level of ‘Warning’, which is a reasonable approach. I tried by creating a function app in a visual studio version 7.0.
- I got the information logs what you have got.

[image]

**host.json:**

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    },
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "None",
      "Function.Function1": "Warning"
    }
  }
}
```

- I am able to retrieve the “warning” logs by AzureClients provided in the application.

[image]

- Any further classification required refer this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74485195/21525734)